# Code can't connect to an AP but Android can

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I have an weird issue with WiFi in that my Android phone can connect to a specific AP using the "native" Settings->Wireless & Network->Connect but I can't connect using my code running on the same phone. However, my code can connect to any other AP. I've searched the postings but couldn't find anything that was helpful. So I am hoping to get help with one of the following questions:

1. Is there an easy way to find the source code that Android executes when the user clicks on Settings->Wireless & Networks->Connect. I can't seem to find it but I've never tried this before either. If someone has a link to cached page it would be greatly appreciated. I know I can download the source code but that is a major project for me now and I am hoping to avoid it.
2. Alternatively, is there a way I can programmatically just execute the same code that Android does without the confirmation dialog box that Android pops up when the user tries to connect to an AP?

Thanks for any and all help.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the source code of the Settings application [via a Web browser](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git;a=tree). The WiFi related classes appear to be in `src/com/android/settings/wifi`.